# how to disable/enable group of linkbutton

Tags: asp.net

I need to disable 4-5 linkbuttons when one of the linkbutton is clicked.On one linkbutton click disable a group of linkbutton and when a session turns null enable all the linkbutton back to enable mode.I tried few methods none of it is truly disabling the linkbutton.

Comment: kindly put your code what you have doen?

Answer (score 0):

Create one OnClick event handler for all link buttons with the code that looks something like this:

```
 lnkBtn1.Enabled = lnkBtn2.Enabled = lnkBtnZ.Enabled = false;
```